# Generic view 'archive_year' produces blank page

Tags: python, django, view, generics

I am using Django's generic views to create a blog site.  The
templates I created, `entry_archive_day`, `entry_archive_month`,
`entry_archive`, and `entry_detail` all work perfectly.

But **`entry_archive_year`** does not.  Instead, it is simply a valid page with no content (not a 404 or other error.  It looks like it sees no objects in `**object_list**`.

I know that `archive` uses a `latest` list instead of `object_list`,
but that's not the case with `archive_year`, correct?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**To solve your problem:**

If you set `make_object_list=True` when calling `archive_year`, then the list of objects for that year will be available as `object_list`.

As a quick example, if your url pattern looks like

```
url(r'^(?P<year>\d{4})/$', 'archive_year', info_dict, name="entry_archive_year")
```

where `info_dict` is a dictionary containing the `queryset` and `date_field`, change it to

```
url(r'^(?P<year>\d{4}/$', 'archive_year', dict(info_dict,make_object_list=True),
        name="entry_archive_year")
```

**Explanation:**

The generic view `archive_year` has an optional argument `make_object_list`. By default, it is set to false, and `object_list` is passed to the template as an empty list.

> `make_object_list`: A boolean specifying whether to retrieve the full list of objects for this year and pass those to the template. If `True`, this list of objects will be made available to the template as `object_list`. (The name `object_list` may be different; see the docs for `object_list` in the "Template context" section below.) By default, this is `False`.

A reason for this is that you might not always want to display the entire object list in the `entry_archive_year` view. You may have hundreds of blog posts for that year, too many to display on one page.

Instead, `archive_year` adds `date_list` to the template context. This allows you to create links to the monthly archive pages of that year, for the months which have entries.

> `date_list`: A list of `datetime.date` objects representing all months that have objects available in the given year, according to queryset, in ascending order.

There's more info in the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/generic-views/#django-views-generic-date-based-archive-year).

**As requested in the comment below, an example of how to use `date_list`:**

To use `date_list`, your `entry_archive_year` template would contain something like this:

```
<ul>
  {% for month in date_list %}

    <li><a href="/blog/{{month|date:"Y"}}/{{month|date:"b"}}>
          {{month|date:"F"}}</a></li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Note that I've hardcoded the url - in practice it would be better to use the [url template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/templates/builtins/#url). For an example of `date_list` being used in the wild, look at the [Django Weblog 2009 Archive](http://www.djangoproject.com/weblog/2009/).

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you for your prompt and articulated answer.  I wasn't sure of how to pass the setting from urls.py, but found this example: http://github.com/garethr/django-train/blob/ed60ace848e39d2d007929b2316d090886887a57/src/train/urls.py

As a follow-up, do you have a link to a good example using date_list?

Comment: I've added an example showing how to change urls.py in case somebody else has the same problem in future, and written a little more about `date_list`.

Comment: This is a fantastic answer - I had the same problem this morning and was banging my head against the wall until I saw this. It needs to be better documented in the Django docs. Thanks Alasdair.